# Search to JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift, uisearchbar

I am trying to find matching keyword in this JSON. For example i want the object that contains sam in either the title, number or array of users.

```
[
    {
        "title":"List of students",
        "number": "12 stu",
        "users":[{
            "id": 12,
            "name":"tom"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name":"sam"
        }]
    },
    {
        "title":"List of tutors",
        "number": "2 tut",
        "users":[{
            "id": 1,
            "name":"John"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name":"Sam"
        }]
    }
]
```

With my code, i can only search through title and number but cant search through each users.

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    arrResf = arrRes.filter({ (item) -> Bool in         
        let heading: NSString = ((item["title"]! as? String)! + (item["number"]! as! String)) as NSString
        return (heading.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound
    })
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

How do i expand my search to include users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = array.filter { item in
  let title = item["title"] as? String ?? ""
  let number = item["number"] as? String ?? ""
  let users = (item["users"] as? [[String: Any]]) ?? []
  let usersString = users.reduce("") { result, dictionary in
    [result, dictionary["name"]].flatMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "\t")
  }
  let finalString = [title, number, usersString].joined(separator: "\t")
  return finalString.lowercased().contains(searchTerm.lowercased())
}
```

Since users is an array of dictionaries, I would use `reduce`, which helps you "reduce" an array to a single value. What I'm doing here is going through all dictionaries in the array and adding the value for `name` to the string.

A couple of details:

- You should avoid converting Swift objects to `NS` objects when possible. It will make your code cleaner.
- Force-unwrapping optionals should be avoided, if your dictionary doesn't have a value for "title" in your code, it will crash. It's better to use the default value operator `??`
- While you can get this to work with dictionaries, I would recommend creating a `struct` that can be initialized from your JSON dictionary.

Comment: This code is fairly inefficient. If the title matches, for example, there is no need to check the number or scan through the users. For a search, this inefficiency may be noticeable depending on the amount of data.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your code. Don't use `NSString` in Swift. Don't force-unwrap optionals.

I would implement your filter as follows:

```
arrResf = arrRes.filter { (item) -> Bool in
    // Check the title
    if let title = item["title"] as? String, title.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
        return true
    }

    // Check the number
    if let number = item["number"] as? String, number.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
        return true
    }

    // Check the users name
    if let users = item["users"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        for user in users {
            if let name = user["name"] as? String, name.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

This code assumes you want to return any item where either the title, number or any of the users' name matches the search text.

Answer (score 0):

Make an Decodable Object from it:

```
struct Item: Decodable {
   let title: String
   let number: String
   let users:[User]
}

struct User: Decodable {
 let id: Int
 let name: String
}
```

After it you can use all power of Array to search your items!